List of objects stored in a companion object has null values when accessed via firstOrNull
I ran into a peculiar problem. I have a base class and a bunch of objects that extend the base class. I added a companion object to the base class with a list of all the objects that extend the base class. However, it seems that in some cases, the objects are not initialized when trying to invoke functions on that list.
Here's the base class, with the companion object:
abstract class MyBaseClass {
    abstract fun getName(): String

    companion object {
        val list = listOf(Foo, Bar)

        fun getByName(name: String): MyBaseClass? {
            return list.firstOrNull { it.getName() == name }
        }
    }
}

And the objects are defined in another file:
object Foo: MyBaseClass() {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "Foo"
    }
}

object Bar: MyBaseClass() {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "Bar"
    }
}

Now, if I call the getByName function, it throws a NullPointerException. However, if I first iterate the list and print the items, it prints out everything correctly and after this, getByName works correctly.
// Throws NPE
@Test
fun testOne() {
    assertEquals(Foo, MyBaseClass.getByName("Foo"))
}

// Works correctly
@Test
fun testTwo() {
    for (o in MyBaseClass.list) {
        println("Object: $o")
    }
    assertEquals(Foo, MyBaseClass.getByName("Foo"))
}

Is this intended behavior, or am I missing something here?

Putting all the declarations in the same file still throws NPE. See https://pl.kotl.in/oqnuu15Dp

@Sweeper thanks, it does indeed. I may have had an error in my code earlier when I tried that out. Removed the mention of the files.

This behaviour is specific to Kotlin/JVM. On Kotlin/JS, this works as expected.
Kotlin objects get compiled to JVM classes with a static field called INSTANCE, e.g. for Foo, the compiled code would roughly translate back to:
public class Foo {
    private Foo() {}
    public static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

    // ...
}

For MyBaseClass, it'd look like this:
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
    public static class Companion {
        private List<MyBaseClass> list = listOf(Foo.INSTANCE, Bar.INSTANCE);

        public List<MyBaseClass> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        private Companion() {}
    }

    public static final Companion Companion = new Companion();
}

When is Foo.INSTANCE initialised? The Java Language Specification says "when the class is initialised" (not to be confused with creating a new instance of a class). When is the class Foo initialised? Just before the first use of Foo. That means the class Foo is initialised when the first argument of assertEquals is evaluated:
assertEquals(Foo, MyBaseClass.getByName("Foo"))
             ^^^

Note that at this point, MyBaseClass.getByName("Foo") has not yet been evaluated, and the class MyBaseClass.Companion has not yet been initialised.
Okay, so let's initialise the class Foo. The first step is to recursively initialise its superclass and the interfaces it implements. So we initialise MyBaseClass, and this causes MyBaseClass.Companion to be initialised, and listOf(Foo, Bar) is executed.
We need to evaluate Foo (i.e. Foo.INSTANCE), but the class Foo has not yet been initialised yet (in fact, it is undergoing initialisation)! The Java Language Specification tells us that nothing will be done in this situation. That is, when we want to initialise a class that is already being initialised, nothing is done. The initialiser of INSTANCE, i.e. new Foo() is not run, and INSTANCE remains null.
As a result, the listOf creates a list with a null and an instance of Bar. Finally, the initialisation of MyBaseClass is complete, and we are back to initialising Foo, and this is where the initialiser of INSTANCE is run.
By iterating through the list first, you are effectively initialising MyBaseClass before initialising Foo. Foo will be initialised when evaluating Foo in the expression listOf(Foo, Bar). Again, we try to initialise its superclass MyBaseClass, which is already being initialised, so we do nothing. Then, the initialiser for Foo.INSTANCE is evaluated, and finally, listOf gets a non-null Foo object.
You don't have to loop through the list. Anything that causes MyBaseClass to initialise before Foo would work. Even an expression like
val x = MyBaseClass.Companion

would cause the initialisation of MyBaseClass.
For the exact quotes in the Java Language Specification, see my answer here, which is about effectively the same problem, but in Java.
The Kotlin/JVM specification is not released yet, so I'm not sure if this is intended or not.

It would be better though to prevent the circular initialization in the first place by choosing another data structure.
